# Google File Service closeFinally() timeout

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I just faced a problem with writing data to Google Cloud Storage using AppEngine FileService.

The problem is timeout related as I think. I created new GS file and write data to it using Tasks. Every task closes FileWriteChannel with close(). But closeFinally() is called in about 2 hours after last write (It is required by my DataFlow). So I do not see any file in GS.

Is it any timeoute between last write and closeFinally()?

Comment: I don't fully understand this question. Do you expect to see the file in GS before you call closeFinally()? Do you expect an automatic call to closeFinally() after a timeout?

Comment: No. The question is how long can I hold AppEngineFile closed without closeFinally. I do not expect automatic closeFinally. I just want to know can I close file and continue to do anything with it after several hours.

Answer (score 1):

There is no timeout between calls to `close()` and `closeFinally()` but you must finalize the upload with a call to `closeFinally()` within a few days after starting the upload with `createNewGSFile()`.

Comment: Hi @fejta, Thanks for your answer above.  I'm running into a potentially related issue where a call to closeFinally() is resulting in a FileServiceImpl.translateException(FileServiceImpl.java:621).  The closeFinally() call is made about 15 mins after the createNewGSFile().  I'm currently on GAE SDK 1.8.2 (will be upgrading in the future) but need to resolve this issue asap for a current customer.  Guessing this might be a timeout of sorts but do you have any other insights?  Thanks!