# Google App Engine: FileServiceImpl.translateException on closeFinally()

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

This may be related to [Google File Service closeFinally() timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764269/google-file-service-closefinally-timeout).

My Java GAE app is running on SDK 1.8.2 and is hitting a translateException when calling closeFinally() on a FileWriteChannel.  I'll be updating the SDK and migrating to the new Cloud Storage API but need to resolve this exception asap for a customer so am wondering if anyone has some insight into the issue for a quick fix.

Here's a simplification of the code that's causing the issue:

```
AppEngineFile writableFile = fileService.createNewGSFile(optionsBuilder.build());
String gcsWritePath = writableFile.getFullPath();
FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(writableFile, true);

for(conditions) {
    Do stuff and write to gcsWritePath
    if(recordsWritten > threshold) {
        Kick off new task with a startAtparam to avoid OOM and timeouts
        break;
    }
}

if(all records written) {
    writeChannel.closeFinally(); // Exception happens here
}
```

And the exception details

java.io.IOException
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.translateException(FileServiceImpl.java:621)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.makeSyncCall(FileServiceImpl.java:594)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.close(FileServiceImpl.java:565)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.close(FileServiceImpl.java:457)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileWriteChannelImpl.closeFinally(FileWriteChannelImpl.java:97)

The exception only appears to occur for longer running tasks (e.g. 5+ minutes) so it looks like this might be a timeout.  I've tried adjusting the threshold without much luck though.  I also tried looking through the app engine sdk source for [FileServiceImpl.java](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/files/FileServiceImpl.java) and [ApiProxy.java](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/apphosting/api/ApiProxy.java) but didn't find any good clues.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing this?